# Computer takes too long to wake after 13.10 update

Tags: 13.10

Right after I updated to 13.10 when I log in after booting a black screen with only the mouse visible occupies the screen for a period of time.

Comment: Did you try pressing Ctrl+Alt+(F1-F7) to change consoles and see if there is one that displays the logging info, showing you what your computer is currently doing (Ctrl+Alt+F7 will get you back to your GUI screen)?

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me because I keep upgrading release after release and my compiz configuration doesn't get recognized. If you had some settings in compiz that have been changed, removed or renamed, the session will take  some time to start trying to read all the settings.

To be sure that's the problem, log in as guest (or create a new user and log in with it) and you'll see that the loading time is much shorter.

My solution some releases ago was deleting all my compiz configuration, forcing the system to create a new profile, with:

```
rm -rvf $HOME/.compiz*
```

Notice that this command will erase any personalization you  may've done, like wallpaper, desktops, etc... but is not difficult to recover the settings.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sadly the same problem seems to occur in other users

Comment: If the problem persist with other users (even newly created) don't know exactly what can be the problem, maybe some items in the startup are delaying the login? Try to remove a few things from gnome-session-properties and see if you get any improvement.

Comment: I'm a beginner and I don't know how to do that, can you help?

Comment: Just run, in a terminal: gnome-session-properties And you'll see a lot of items. You can disable some of them deselecting them on the left tick boxes. To be safe, search on the net for their names before you do it, to know what each of them do (may depend on what programs you have installed) and then disable a few, log out and log in again. If by any chance you disable something you shouldn't and the system acts weird, just run the program again and re-enable the last one you changed.